# On Xamarin De Android platform, I can not list my data in ListView continuously with Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin

In Xamarin on Android platform, I can not list my data in the ListView constantly with the WebService, I do not update the changed query results in the ListView list but only the results in the first query remain on the screen. With the service, the query is refreshed once every 5 seconds. I can see that the results vary but I can not list, can you help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding ogrenciModels}" x:Name="AnonsList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell Height="100" 
                               Text="{Binding AdSoyad}"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               Detail="{Binding VeliAdSoyad}"
                               DetailColor="DarkGreen"  
                               ImageSource="{Binding OgrenciFoto}">
                    </ImageCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

```
       <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding ogrenciModels}" x:Name="AnonsList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell Height="100" 
                               Text="{Binding AdSoyad}"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               Detail="{Binding VeliAdSoyad}"
                               DetailColor="DarkGreen"  
                               ImageSource="{Binding OgrenciFoto}">
                    </ImageCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: foreach (string item in Anonslistesi)
            {
                string[] AnonsBilgisiParcala = item.ToString().Split('|');

                ogrenciModels.Add(new OgrenciModel()
                {
                    AdSoyad = AnonsBilgisiParcala[17].ToString(),
                   VeliAdSoyad = AnonsBilgisiParcala[18].ToString(),
                    OgrenciFoto = "http://........jpg"
                }
                );
            }
            return ogrenciModels;

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OgrenciModel
{
    public int OgrenciID { get; set; }
    public string KurumKod { get; set; }
    public DateTime Tarih { get; set; }
    public DateTime Saat { get; set; }
    public string adi { get; set; }
    public string soyadi { get; set; }
    public string AdSoyad { get; set; }
    public string Sinif { get; set; }
    public string EtutSinif { get; set; }
    public string KayitNo { get; set; }
    public string Yon { get; set; }
    public string VeliAdi { get; set; }
    public string VeliSoyadi { get; set; }
    public string VeliAdSoyad { get; set; }
    public string VeliYakinlik { get; set; }
    public string OgrenciFoto { get; set; }
    public string VeliFoto { get; set; }


    public List<OgrenciModel> GetOgrenciModels()
    {
        string Kurumkod = Settings.SettingsKurumKodu.ToString();
        string[] Sinif = Settings.SettingsSinifAdi.Split(',');

        if (Kurumkod != null && Sinif[0] != "Seçilmedi!")
        {
            string Tarih = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string Saat = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-3).ToString("HH:mm:ss"); // güncel zamanın 3 saniye gerisine gider.
            string sorgu = "SELECT ...............;
            string AnonsSorgusu = Provider.ServiceManager.SorguGonder(sorgu);
            string[] Anonslistesi = AnonsSorgusu.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
            List<OgrenciModel> ogrenciModels = new List<OgrenciModel>();
            foreach (string item in Anonslistesi)
            {
                string[] AnonsBilgisiParcala = item.ToString().Split('|');

                ogrenciModels.Add(new OgrenciModel()
                {
                    AdSoyad = AnonsBilgisiParcala[17].ToString(),
                   VeliAdSoyad = AnonsBilgisiParcala[18].ToString(),
                    OgrenciFoto = "http://........jpg"
                }
                );
            }
            return ogrenciModels;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please EDIT your question to include additional detail.  The ANSWER function should only be used if you are actually providing an answer to the question.